# How Can i convert MPP file into CSV using Script

Tags: java, python, csv, automation

I was trying to fetch data from MPP file , Since it is hard i was thinking about converting the MPP file into something more readable and have some library support, Is there any way to convert MPP file into CSV by script

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many online converters to convert mpp to csv. One of them are [MPP to CSV](https://products.groupdocs.app/conversion/mpp-to-csv)

Also you can visit [Automate MPP to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671475/any-way-to-automate-the-process-of-opening-a-mpp-file-and-saving-it-as-a-csv) for references.

Comment: Thanks Shag , But i want to automate the process , i tried with MPXJ library - Is there any other solution

Comment: So it didn't workout with MPXJ library? because there is whole script for references [MPJX](http://www.mpxj.org/howto-convert.html)